# PassengerDetailsRQ for round trip

Tags: php, soap, sabre

We're working on integration of API in our system.We had done pretty well for the one way trip and generate PNR successfully but we are stock on the PassengerDetailsRQ for round trip. I am sure BargainFinderMaxRQ is correct for round trip but we are confused on EnhancedAirBookRQ  too . So , I am attaching both EnhancedAirBookRQ and PassengerDetailsRQ for round trip here. Hope some help from sabre.

**EnhancedAirBookRQ :**

```
<EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2" HaltOnError="false" version="3.2.0">
      <OTA_AirBookRQ>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UC"/>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="LL"/>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UN"/>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="NO"/>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="HL"/>
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
          <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2016-09-02T09:50:00" FlightNumber="263" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="O" Status="NN">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL"/>
            <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="263"/>
            <OperatingAirline Code="9W"/>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
          </FlightSegment>
          <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2016-09-22T13:45:00" FlightNumber="260" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="S" Status="NN">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
            <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="260"/>
            <OperatingAirline Code="9W"/>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="DEL"/>
          </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
      </OTA_AirBookRQ>
      <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
        <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
          <OptionalQualifiers>
            <PricingQualifiers>
              <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
            </PricingQualifiers>
          </OptionalQualifiers>
        </PriceRequestInformation>
      </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
      <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false">
        <RedisplayReservation WaitInterval="2000"/>
      </PostProcessing>
      <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false"/>
    </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

**PassengerDetailsRQ :**

```
 <PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_1" version="3.1.0">
      <MiscSegmentSellRQ>
        <MiscSegment DepartureDateTime="09-02" NumberInParty="1" Status="NN" Type="OTH">
          <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
          <Text>RETENTION SEGMENT</Text>
          <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Code="9W"/>
          </VendorPrefs>
        </MiscSegment>
        <MiscSegment DepartureDateTime="09-22" NumberInParty="1" Status="NN" Type="OTH">
          <OriginLocation LocationCode="DEL"/>
          <Text>RETENTION SEGMENT</Text>
          <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Code="9W"/>
          </VendorPrefs>
        </MiscSegment>
      </MiscSegmentSellRQ>
      <PostProcessing>
        <EndTransactionRQ>
          <EndTransaction Ind="true"/>
          <Source ReceivedFrom="TARA TESTING"/>
        </EndTransactionRQ>
      </PostProcessing>
      <PriceQuoteInfo>
        <Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1"/>
      </PriceQuoteInfo>
      <SpecialReqDetails>
        <AddRemarkRQ>
          <RemarkInfo>
            <FOP_Remark Type="CASH"/>
            <Remark Type="General">
              <Text>TEST GENERAL REMARK</Text>
            </Remark>
          </RemarkInfo>
        </AddRemarkRQ>
        <SpecialServiceRQ>
          <SpecialServiceInfo>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="DOCS">
              <PersonName DateOfBirth="1990-02-07" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
                <GivenName>Kiran</GivenName>
                <Surname>Subedi</Surname>
              </PersonName>
              <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="false"/>
              </VendorPrefs>
            </SecureFlight>
          </SpecialServiceInfo>
        </SpecialServiceRQ>
      </SpecialReqDetails>
      <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
        <AgencyInfo>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine>TARA TRAVEL</AddressLine>
            <CityName>Kathmandu</CityName>
            <CountryCode>NP</CountryCode>
            <PostalCode>977</PostalCode>
            <StateCountyProv StateCode="KTM"/>
            <StreetNmbr>3150 DDDD DRIVE</StreetNmbr>
          </Address>
          <Ticketing TicketType="7TAW"/>
        </AgencyInfo>
        <CustomerInfo>
          <ContactNumbers>
            <ContactNumber LocationCode="KTM" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="9846231634" PhoneUseType="H"/>
          </ContactNumbers>
          <Email Address="subedikiran41@gmail.com" NameNumber="1.1"/>
          <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT">
            <GivenName>Kiran</GivenName>
            <Surname>Subedi</Surname>
          </PersonName>
        </CustomerInfo>
      </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
    </PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

Comment: Your EnhancedAirBook request seems to be okay for a roundtrip (it includes both outbuond and inbound flights).

Creating Miscelaneous segments (<MiscSegment ....>) is not mandatory for PassengerDetails, unless you really need them (not even for a one way).

Are you getting any error since you say you are stuck?

Comment: I get error lik `Message validation failed. Errors: [cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'MiscSegment'. No child element is expected at this point.]` in PassengerDetailsRQ. Can you please provide me the request format for round trip ?

Comment: It `<MiscSegment>` is not passed I get error like `ITINERARY REQUIRED TO COMPLETE TRANSACTION` . `fcarreno` is there any solution for this ??

Comment: MiscSegment is not required to complete a PNR, but an itinerary is.

Now, if you get that error, then it means that your EnhancedAirBook request was not successful. Are you not making the EnhancedAirBook call first,(to book the flights and include them in the itinerary) and then (using the same BinarySecurityToken) calling PassengerDetails?

BTW, the call to PassengerDetails does not need to know whether your itinerary is round trip or one way...

Comment: Thanks `fcarreno`  for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MiscSegment is not required to complete a PNR, but an itinerary is.

Are you not making the EnhancedAirBook call first,(to book the flights and include them in the itinerary) and then (using the same BinarySecurityToken) calling PassengerDetails? BTW, the call to PassengerDetails does not need to know whether your itinerary is round trip or one way...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove "MiscSegmentSellRQ" from "PassengerDetailsRQ" and it will help you.